# How can I compute distances between elements in a list and get a "sorted and without duplicate" list in return?

Tags: python, lambda

Let's say I have the following list:
[1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14]

I want to compute distances between element of this list so that:
∀i ∈ [0, . . . , s − 2], D(i) = O(i + 1) − O(i)
so the list of distances would be :
[1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2]

Last step, I want this list of distances to be sorted and without duplicate, so the final result would be:
[1, 2, 3, 4]

What would be the most efficient way to do so ?

So far I have the following code:

```
        for i in range(0, len(elements) - 1):
            distances.append(elements[i + 1] - elements[i])

       lst_output = list(set(distances))
       lst_output.sort()
```

It works but there must be better ways to do this, using lambda function I suppose.

How would you do  so ?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do such a script in less than 4 lines ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might me faster:

```
elements =  [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14]
distances = []

for i in range(0, len(elements) - 1):
    distances.append(elements[i + 1] - elements[i])

distances.sort()

print(distances)

i = 0
while i < len(distances)-1:
    while distances[i] == distances[i + 1]:
        distances.pop(i)
    i += 1
print(distances)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe more efficient solution is to add the items immediately to the set:

```
s = set()
for i in range(len(elements) - 1):
  s.add(elements[i+1] - elements[i])
lst_output = list(s) # this is already sort
```

Comment: inserting to set though comes with big complexity

Comment: each time set reallocates, it has to be rehashed

Comment: it also fails if some difference is negative number

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution for you would be to use dict as follow:

```py
elements = [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14]
distances = []
for i in range(0, len(elements) - 1):
    distances.append(elements[i + 1] - elements[i])

final_lst_output= list(dict.fromkeys(distances))
print(sorted(final_lst_output))
```

which will give you

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to have both the basic difference list and the non-duplicate sorted differences, you can get them compactly:

```py
distances = [ thisel - elements[i] for i,thisel in enumerate(elements[1:]) ]
lst_output = sorted(set(distances))
```

Notice that the list comprehension starts at the second element of `elements` (`[1]`), but since the `enumerate` will start at `0` the difference is between successive values. If the `distances` list is not needed, the comprehension can go into the `set` constructor.

Generally list comprehensions are efficient. If maintainability is important and this code might be misunderstood, the simple loop generation of distance might be better.